# Accessing data from localhost. worked in android but does not in web browser

Tags: android, http, flutter-web

I want to access data from local host and did all the necessary steps needed from the flutter documentation. The code was working fine and all the requirements were fulfilled when working with an android emulator. But now when I am debugging for web (on the google chrome browser on windows), the data access part of the code (`http.get(url)`) is not working. Here is my code:

```
String url = "http://10.0.2.2:5000/";

onPressed: () async {
            print('1');
            var Data = await back_end(url);
            print('2');
            var DecodedData = jsonDecode(Data);
            setState(() {
              val = Data;
            });
          },
Future back_end(url) async{
  http.Response Resp = await http.get(url);
  return Resp.body;
}
```

the flutter output only prints out '1' and does not print '2'(it gets struck waiting for a response from http.get) when I run the app on a browser. But I dont have this problem when working with the android emulator. And also, I am able to access the sample json from jsonplaceholders website.

Comment: `url` ?? We dont know what you do. Please start your code defining url and assigning a value. We wanna see where you try to connect to.

Comment: `But now when I am debugging for web` ?? What do you mean by that?

Comment: `Both get printed when I run the same app on an android.` ?? Then what did you do before where '2' was not printed? Where did you run it before?

Comment: `worked in android but does not in web browser` A webbrowser Where? On your PC? On your Android phone?

Comment: @blackapps  url is the adress of my localhost. by debugging for web, I meant that I am now working on the web version of the app and came across this issue when i am doing the same. When both 1 and 2 are getting printed, I was running the app on the android emulator from android studios. The web browser is on my PC. Sorry for not being specific, this was my first question. If there is something that I need to add on in the question please let me know

Comment: You should have edited your post instead of putting the requested info in a comment. Now your post stays unreadable. `url is the adress of my localhost` That is bad info. You should define that in the code block of your post with full url so we can see what you do.

Comment: @blackapps i have already edited my post before answering to your question. I am sure what you mean is answered in the edit.

Comment: `String url = "http://10.0.2.2:5000/";` You can only use 10.0.2.2. if your app is running on an emulator. Where does it run now? As i still see there `when I am debugging for web` and you did not explain what you ment by it. Nor did you tell where your app was running now. `when I run the app on a browser.` And the browser runs on your emulator, pc or Android device? Put all info in your post please.

Comment: @blackapps I put that info the one of the comments, and now after reading your comment, I have put that into the post as well. Thanks for the suggest. I have tried using the regular localhost adress(localhost:5000/), the ip adress of my system, and also the localhost ip adress (127.0.0.1:5000/). Please let me know if there is something else that could help

Comment: 127.0.0.1 or localhost should do for Chrome on PC. What kind of server is installed on that pc? If you just manually type 127.0.0.1:5000 in address bar of Chrome... then what happens?

Comment: @blackapps I have a flask server installed in local host to access the APIs developed (python). typing localhost in chrome takes me to the homepage of my server without any problem.